# Highcharts - xAxis labels amount

Tags: highcharts

While using Highcharts i come across the following problem after implementing my navigator.

In specific zoom areas many tick labels appear on xAxis creating a mess.
Example in this image.
[image: Many Labels]

But when i zoom out a bit for example the xAxis labels automatically transform to:

[image]

Is there a way to have a specific amount of ticks each time to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem in this demo?
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line

Probably some options for ticks are influencing this behavior:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minorTicks

Comment: Unfortunately its overwhelming to do that. I will try though.

Comment: Hello @madepiet unfortunately i can not reproduce this problem in jsfiddle for example... i will try minorticks as said though